# Whats wrong with this PowerShell script?

Tags: sql, powershell, filestream

I am trying to export sql filestream data using powershell script and it exports only upto 8kb and it fails to export if the file is more than 8kb. But it creates the file partially. I dont know what is missing.

```
$Server = "(local)";              # SQL Server Instance.            
$Database = "AdventureWorks";            
$Dest = "D:\Export\";             # Path to export to.            
$bufferSize = 8192;               # Stream buffer size in bytes.            

$con = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;            
$con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$Server;" +             
                    "Integrated Security=True;" +            
                    "Initial Catalog=$Database";            
$con.Open();            

[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction]$tran = $con.BeginTransaction("fs");            
$Sql = "SELECT GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT()";            
$ctx = [array]::CreateInstance('Byte', 16);            
$cmdct = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Sql, $con, $tran);            
$ctx = $cmdct.ExecuteScalar();            
$cmdct.Dispose();            

$Sql = "SELECT [FileName] 
          ,[FileStreamData].PathName()
    FROM dbo.FileStreamStorage ";            

$out = [array]::CreateInstance('Byte', $bufferSize);            

$cmd = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Sql, $con, $tran);            
$rd = $cmd.ExecuteReader();            

While ($rd.Read())            
{            
Write-Output ("Exporting: {0}" -f $rd.GetString(0));                    

$fs = New-Object System.IO.FileStream ($Dest + $rd.GetString(0)), Create, Write;            
$bw = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($fs);            
$sfs = New-Object System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream $rd.GetString(1), $ctx, Read, None, 0;            

$start = 0;            
While (1 -eq 1)            
{                             
   $received = $sfs.Read($out, $start, $bufferSize - 1);            
   $bw.Write($out, 0, $received);            
   $bw.Flush();            
   $start += $received;            

   If ($received -lt $bufferSize)            
   { break; }            
}            

$bw.Close();            
$fs.Close();            
$sfs.Close();            
}            

$fs.Dispose();            
$sfs.Dispose();            
$rd.Close();            
$rd.Dispose();            
$tran.Commit();            
$cmd.Dispose();            
$tran.Dispose();            
$con.Close();            
$con.Dispose();            

Write-Output ("Finished");
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Any errors? Exceptions?

Comment: No. It creates the file all the time but the issue is if the file is more than 8kb in size, it creates until 8kb and not writing the remaining bytes in the file. As the result the files cannot be opened due to corruption.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are reading 8191 bytes, which means that $received will be 8191 if theres more data than this.

```
$received = $sfs.Read($out, $start, **$bufferSize - 1**);
```

Then you compare $received (8191) to $bufferSize (8192)

```
If ($received -lt $bufferSize)
```

Comment: I removed the -1 but now I am getting an error saying "Offset and length were out of bounds of the array. Please help...

Comment: Maybe try to change the if statement instead? Like this: if ($received -lt $bufferSize -1)

Comment: The idea of exporting a filestream to an array seems wrong.  There's only going to be one data element in the stream.  It seems to be trying to populate it all into the first array element and running into the array definition constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some work with filestreams and Powershell and I would agree with other comments--It appears there's an issue in how you are getting the length. Here's some code from my blog http://sev17.com/2010/05/11/t-sql-tuesday-006-blobs-filestream-and-powershell/ which demonstrates retrieving filestream data to a an image file:

```
$server = "Z002sql2k8"
$database = "AdventureWorks2008"
$query = "SELECT TOP(10) Document.PathName(), GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT(), Title + FileExtension AS FileName FROM Production.Document WHERE FileExtension = '.doc'"
$dirPath = "C:Usersu00"

$connection=new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
$connection.ConnectionString="Server={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=True" -f $server,$database
$connection.Open()
$command=new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("",$connection)
$command.CommandTimeout=120
$tran = $connection.BeginTransaction([System.Data.IsolationLevel]'ReadCommitted')
$command.Transaction = $tran
$command.CommandText = $query
$reader = $command.ExecuteReader()
while ($reader.Read())
{
    $path = $reader.GetString(0)
    [byte[]]$transactionContext = $reader.GetSqlBytes(1).Buffer
    $filepath = "$dirPath{0}" -f $reader.GetValue(2)

    $fileStream = new-object System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream($path,[byte[]]$reader.GetValue(1), [System.IO.FileAccess]'Read', [System.IO.FileOptions]'SequentialScan', 0)
    $buffer = new-object byte[] $fileStream.Length
    $fileStream.Read($buffer,0,$fileStream.Length)
    $fileStream.Close()
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($filepath,$buffer)

}

$reader.Close()
$tran.Commit()
$connection.Close()
```

Comment: But I am getting "The file is being used by another process" error when using the above script.

Comment: Probably another process locking file like AV or backup software. You could use Sysinternals Process Monitor to figure out what process locking file.